# Event when resources of page are loaded in WinRT

Tags: c#, events, resources, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

What event are start when resources of page are loaded?
(Resources like localization's strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor you get an `InitializeComponent()` call which loads the stuff in your XAML, where the resources are typically added. After that I think you can assume they are loaded. If any of these does some other loading - you might need to wait for it to finish with some targeted code that will depend on the resource you are waiting for.

*EDIT

Note that in UWP apps (Windows 10) - resources are typically lazy-loaded. That is - while the resource may get created when the XAML it's defined in is loaded with say `InitializeComponent()` - the resources themselves only get constructed when they are first referenced - either with `Static/Theme-Resource` markup extension or from code behind by accessing them with the resource dictionary's [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).
Also note that the resources in App.xaml get created once for each application window even though there may be only a single Application class instance, since different windows use separate dispatchers.